# Were the Project Genesis Summary animations computer generated?

Tags: star-trek, the-wrath-of-khan, cgi

These animations looked pretty good for 1984.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Were they computer generated, or how were they produced?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. These sequences were indeed computer-generated. As you can see from the video below, an extensive CGI sequence was created by the wizards at [ILM](http://www.ilm.com/)

Some additional "*hand-painting*" was also used, but this was all digital as well and done on computer-aided art programs.

The 'rolling fire' effect is discussed in the Open University video below and was accomplished using compositing and matting to create a wall of over a hundred-thousand big fuzzy pixels